# Find out possible number of simultaneous bluetooth connections

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to multiple bluetooth low energy BLE devices simultaneously, is there a methods or way that let me know how many simultaneous connections a device supports. As number of simultaneous connections varies depending on vendor as according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365009/what-is-the-max-concurrent-ble-connections-android-m-can-have/41367864) answer there is a constant that defines the number of simultaneous connection, is there a way to read that constant ?

Comment: No you can't. But you can try to connect device after device until it fails.